# How to integrate Memory Pool concept into data structure (e.g. custom array)?

Tags: c++, c++11, game-engine, pool, memory-pool

I have been using component-entity system.
Long time ago, I wanted to improve it to use **memory pool**.

### Phase 1

For simplicity, here is my ancient code :-

```
Entity* entity      =new Entity();             
Com_Physic* comPhys =new Com_Physic();
```

This is a result from refactoring :-

```
Ptr<Entity> entity=centerPool()->createEntity();                   //use pool
Ptr<Com_Physic> comPhys=centerPool()->create<Com_Physic>(entity);  //use pool
```

It works really good. (time used per timestep-=10%)

### Phase 2

Now I have a strong desire to adapt the **memory pool** concept everywhere.
However, in cases that involved some data-structures, it is hard.

Here is an example function that return all (default) physics body of a certain entity.
It is not a real complete code, but good enough to show the problematic part :-

```
class SystemPhysic : public basicSystem {
    //..... other function / field .....
    public: MyArray<PhysicObject*> getAllPhysicBody(Ptr<Entity> entity){
        Ptr<Com_Physic> comPhysic=entity->get<Com_Physic>();
        MyArray<PhysicObject*> allPhy=comPhysic->physicsList; 
                                   //^ #problem
        return allPhy;
    }
};
```

`MyArray<T>` is a custom array similar as `std::vector`.    It uses its own allocator.

Here is its core:-

```
void reserve(int expectedSize){
    //......
    void* databaseNew=operator new [](expectedSize*sizeof(T));
    //......
}
```

Therefore, whenever I call `MyArray<PhysicObject*>::operator=()`,
... roughly speaking, `operator new[]` will be called.  (`#problem`)

Memory is fragmented again.

## Question

Should general data-structures use the memory pool concept?
If so, how to integrate memory pool concept into data-structure professionally?

I just want a rough idea.
A solution that contained no code at all is acceptable.

### More technical information

There are 2 type of problems about `MyArray<T>`:-

1. `MyArray<T>` as a field of Component (e.g. `Com_Physic`).
2. `MyArray<T>` as a temporary message that pass from a system to another system.   It is created fast, delete fast. (>70% , life time = 1 time-step)

I have an idea to divide it in 2 cases, `ShortLife_MyArray<T>` & `LongLife_MyArray<T>`,
... but I think I make it too complex and far harder to maintain.

To make the problem worse, in a real game, there are also many kinds of data-structure besides `MyArray<T>`, e.g. `MyArray<T1,T2>`,`MyMap<T1,T2>`,`MySet<T1,&FunctionPointer>`, etc.

## My poor solutions

This just shows a list of my guess so far.

### Solution 1 (singleton, static)

Create a static pool field in `MyArray<T>`, `MyArray<T1,T2>`,`MyMap<T1,T2>`, etc.

All types data-structures have to use that static pool to allocate memory when needed.

```
GlobalDataStructure::staticPool=topLevel()->poolPtr; 
//called only once before everything start
```

**Disadvantage:-**

- It is a static variable. (not make sense much)
- It is moderately hard to find where the global-setting statement should be called.
- (weak) I can use only 1 pool. (I am not sure if it is a problem.)
- (weak)  I have to use `mutex` to lock the pool if my game is multi-thread.

### Solution 2 (the upper hand)

Create a non-static pool field in `MyArray<T>`, `MyArray<T1,T2>`,`MyMap<T1,T2>`, etc.

Whenever I want to create a new data-structure,
... I have to ***pass*** the shared pool (from top-level game logic).

```
MyArray<T> arr=MyArray<T>(topLevel()->poolPtr);  //messy
```

There can be many pools for different situation.   It is probably good.

When data-structures want to allocate, it must use that pool.

**Disadvantage:-**

- I have to refactor all codes for all types of data-structure.
- I have to ***pass*** the pool.   The code would be a little more dirty.
- (weak) I have to use `mutex` to lock the pool if my game is multi-thread.

### Solution 3 (lazy way)

Don't do anything, pools for entity and component should be enough.
The others solution are over-engineering.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this can be answered on Stack Overflow. There are pros and cons to various solutions, and ultimately you have to decide what kind of trade offs you're willing to make and what kind of things you prefer. Ultimately it's a matter of opinion once you consider the technical facts. I might recommend asking this on [GameDev.net](https://www.gamedev.net/) (disclaimer: I haven't been there in years and don't know if it's still as good as it used to be), or some other forum where you can have a proper discussion with people.

Comment: @Cornstalks Thank.  I am a beginner, so I just guess there might be the best single solution that I have never thought of.  (If my assumption is correct, this is not a subjective discussion.)    I wish, at least, I could get some confirmation like "experts would select this X solution".    I will post elsewhere as you recommend if I don't get answer.  :)

Comment: Maybe MyArray<> can take an Allocator parameter like STL containers do?  Then it won't use `new` if you don't want it to.

Comment: @John Zwinck Great idea, I never thought about it.

Comment: I would not expect that completely replacing malloc by a single, general, global memory pool would yield much benefit, because you end up reimplementing malloc. The advantages usually stem from having specialized memory pools that are tuned for a particular situation.

Comment: @MikeMB Your comment enlightens me, thank!   Solution 2 may be the way to go.